# Copying multiple types of files in one command

Tags: command-line, wildcards, cp

I want to copy several files from one directory to another, with different extensions

So I would write something like:

```
cp -r dir1/*.gif dir2
```

But I also want to copy all .jpg files in the same command. Is there some sort of AND command that would work?

Comment: Small wording detail: If you want `jpg` matches AND `gif` matches, this is technically an OR expression, because you want to match either pattern1 OR pattern2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply list them all:

```
cp dir1/*.gif dir1/*.jpg dir2
```

The way this works is that the shell expands out the `*` parameters and passes  all the matching names to `cp` so it might actually run

```
cp dir1/file1.gif dir1/file2.gif dir1/file3.jpg dir1/file4.jpg dir2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cp /path/src/*.{gif,jpg} /path/dest
```

Info about [wildcards and globbing patterns](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm).

In particular:

```
{ } (curly brackets)
terms are separated by commas and each term must be the name of something or a wildcard. This wildcard will copy anything that matches either wildcard(s), or exact name(s) (an “or” relationship, one or the other).

For example, this would be valid:

cp {*.doc,*.pdf} ~
This will copy anything ending with .doc or .pdf to the users home directory. Note that spaces are not allowed after the commas (or anywhere else).
```

Comment: Better cite the explanation for `{,}` instead of trusting on external links

Answer (score 0):

For loops are nice for this kind of thing.

Example: Copy all .py and .ipynb files from the current directory to a directory called dst/

```
for file in *.py *.ipynb; do cp $file /dst/; done
```

Comment: Could you explain what benefit there is to using a loop instead of `cp -- *.py *.ipynb /dst/`?

Comment: A for loop is more versatile in that you can use any command, as well as chain several commands together.

Other than for copying/renaming files, I also use this pattern often when I'm doing text replacement with sed.
The possibilities are limitless.

Comment: I didn’t mean for you to explain it (to me) in a comment; please [edit] your answer to improve the explanation. And while the possibilities are limitless, we tend to prefer answers within the scope of the question (which is about `cp` in particular here, so ideally you’d explain why a `for` loop is better specifically with `cp`).